# Java 8 - How convert Pojo into list of its embedded Pojo property

Tags: java, java-8

I have a database call which possibly return null if none of criteria matched. If there is record match, the result is a Pojo which contains list of embedded object. I want to convert that Pojo into list of its embedded object id.

Foo.class has the list of Bars

```
public class Foo {
    private List<Bar> bars;
    //..setters & getters
}
```

Bar.class, I want to convert Foo into list of Bar's Id

```
public class Bar {
    Integer id
    //..setters & getters
}
```

I tired using Optional but it always returning into list of bars

```
Optional.ofNullable(fooRepo.search("some foo"))
    .map(foo -> foo.getBars()); //How can turn this into list of Bar's Id
```

Comment: Your question is completely opaque; what is that "database call which possibly returns null"? Where is it called from? How is it related to the code you have posted so far? What is fooService? Etc etc. Please post _all_ the relevant code.

Comment: The database call return null if none of the criteria is matched, so by theory Java 8 Optional is useful here

Comment: And that database is what? Where is it called? You failed to answer any of the questions I asked so far

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(fooRepo.search("some foo"))
    .map(foo -> foo.getBars()); //How can turn this into list of Bar's Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Optional.ofNullable(foo).map(Foo::getBars).map(y -> y.stream().map(z -> z.id).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Full tested code:

```
public class Test {
    public static class Bar {
        public Bar(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        Integer id;
    }

    public static class Foo {
        private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

        public List<Bar> getBars() {
            return bars;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argb) {
        Foo nullFoo = null;
        Optional<List<Integer>> nullList = convertToIdList(nullFoo);
        System.out.println(nullList); // Optional.empty

        Foo notNullFoo = new Foo();
        notNullFoo.getBars().add(new Bar(3));
        notNullFoo.getBars().add(new Bar(4));
        notNullFoo.getBars().add(new Bar(5));
        Optional<List<Integer>> notNullList = convertToIdList(notNullFoo);
        System.out.println(notNullList); // Optional[[3, 4, 5]]
    }

    private static Optional<List<Integer>> convertToIdList(Foo foo) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(foo).map(Foo::getBars).map(y -> y.stream().map(z -> z.id).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

The key thing is to treat the list itself as an Optional, but if it is present to transform that single list from one element type to another. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain I understand your question but I'm interpreting it as:

> A database query can return an object containing a list of references to another object, or null if no references are returned. How do I convert that object (or null) into a list of values from the referenced objects. I want an empty list if the query returned a null.

If I've got your question correct, then I suggest:

```
Optional<Foo> possibleFoo = Optional.ofNullable(dbQuery());
List<Integer> ids = possibleFoo
    .map(f -> f.bars.stream()
        .map(b -> b.id)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .orElse(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```

Comment: Nice extrapolation there "I want an empty list if the query returned a null", I should have assumed that too.

Comment: @IanLovejoy I have no idea if that's what OP intended in the question - it is pretty poorly worded. But it seemed to make sense to return an empty list rather than an `Optional.empty()`.